# Imprimir solo el día en lugar de la fecha completa, con Javascript

Tags: javascript, date

¿Cómo hago para que en este código, en vez de que me imprima la fecha completa, solo sea el día?
Cabe destacar que debo usar `map` para la conversión de fecha a día (en número). No sé si está correcto que puse la fecha con dobles comillas y por esto no puedo imprimir el día; intenté con `getDay()` pero no me funciona.

```js
const trans = [{
    nombre: "prestamo1",
    fecha: "2021-04-05"
  },
  {
    nombre: "prestamo2",
    fecha: "2020-10-09"
  },
  {
    nombre: "prestamo3",
    fecha: '2021-3-2'
  }
];
const regresarfecha = function(trans) {
  return trans.fecha;
}
const fechaPrestamo = trans.map(regresarfecha);
console.log(fechaPrestamo)
```

Comment: ¿Día de la semana? ¿del mes? ¿del año? ¿o solo el dígito del día? ej.: 2020/10/09 => 9.

Answer (score 1):

Para lograr mostrar solo el día puedes crear un objeto [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) a partir de tu string y luego obtener el dato que necesitas.

Esto sería:

```js
const trans = [
  {
    nombre: "prestamo1",
    fecha: "2021-04-05"
  },
  {
    nombre: "prestamo2",
    fecha: "2020-10-09"
  },
  {
    nombre: "prestamo3",
    fecha: '2021-3-2'
  }
];
const regresarfecha = function(trans){
  return new Date(trans.fecha).getDate(); // Acá creas un Date y le pides el día con el método "getDate" 
  // Puedes ver qué otros métodos existen en la documentación compartida abajo.
}
const fechaPrestamo = trans.map(regresarfecha);
console.log(fechaPrestamo)
```

---

Puedes ver más información sobre [Date.getDate()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate). Ten en cuenta que también existe un método [Date.getDay()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay) que devuelve el día de la semana entre 0 y 6 empezando en 0 en domingo.

Puedes ver mas información sobre el objeto `Date` [aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Answer (score 1):

Suponiendo que el día sea el ultimo que colocaste en cada fecha yo creo que podrías utilizar split, separando el arreglo que ya tienes de las fechas ahora por los guiones de las mismas dandole el limite de caracteres que tienes que en este caso son 3 (se representa como 2 en arreglos) y quedaría así:

```js
const trans = [
      {
        nombre: "prestamo1",
        fecha: "2021-04-05"
      },
      {
        nombre: "prestamo2",
        fecha: "2020-10-09"
      },
      {
        nombre: "prestamo3",
        fecha: '2021-3-2'
      }
    ];
    const regresarfecha = (trans) => {
      const toda = trans.fecha.split("-",3); //Las fechas de trans divididas por los guiones y la cantidad de datos que quiero que cubra de cada fecha
      const dia = toda[2] //todos los elementos en la posicion 2, los devuelve como un arreglo
      return dia;
    }
    const fechaPrestamo = trans.map(regresarfecha);
    console.log(fechaPrestamo);//los 3 días juntos
    console.log(fechaPrestamo[0]);//1°
    console.log(fechaPrestamo[1]);//2°
    console.log(fechaPrestamo[2]);//3°
```

btw, espero haberte ayudado